Prevent CloudTrail from logging CloudWatch events
I have a CloudTrail setup to log management events, however monthly costs have risen to an unjustifiable amount for the service. Having done a little investigation, 90% of the events seem to be Lambdas writing to the CloudWatch Log, and also read activities.
Ideally I would like to log only write events, and exclude CloudWatch altogether.
Firstly I tried adjusting the existing CloudTrail with readOnly set to false, and excluding logs.amazaon.aws.com like so:
aws cloudtrail put-event-selectors --trail-name existing-management-trail --region eu-west-1 --advanced-event-selectors "[{\"Name\":\"Write Management Events (Excluding CloudWatch)\",\"FieldSelectors\":[{\"Field\":\"eventCategory\",\"Equals\":[\"Management\"]},{\"Field\":\"readOnly\",\"Equals\":[\"false\"]},{\"Field\":\"eventSource\",\"NotEquals\":[\"logs.amazonaws.com\"]}]}]"

An error occurred (InvalidEventSelectorsException) when calling the PutEventSelectors operation: The specified eventSource selectors are not supported when eventCategory is set to "Equals": "Management".

Then I thought that if you cannot place filters on the management events, I would create a brand new one, and specify the individual resources that I would like to track:
aws cloudtrail create-trail --name test-trail --s3-bucket-name aws-cloudtrail-test-writeonly --is-multi-region-trail --region eu-west-1

aws cloudtrail put-event-selectors --trail-name test-trail --region eu-west-1 --advanced-event-selectors "[{\"Name\":\"Write Events (Excluding CloudWatch)\",\"FieldSelectors\":[{\"Field\":\"resources.type\",\"Equals\":[\"AWS::IAM::User\",\"AWS::IAM::Role\",\"AWS::IAM::Policy\",\"AWS::S3::Bucket\",\"AWS::EC2::Instance\",\"AWS::EC2::Volume\",\"AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup\",\"AWS::RDS::DBInstance\",\"AWS::Lambda::Function\",\"AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer\",\"AWS::CloudFormation::Stack\",\"AWS::EKS::Cluster\",\"AWS::SNS::Topic\",\"AWS::SQS::Queue\",\"AWS::Route53::HostedZone\",\"AWS::SecretsManager::Secret\",\"AWS::KMS::Key\"]},{\"Field\":\"readOnly\",\"Equals\":[\"false\"]}]}]"

An error occurred (UnsupportedOperationException) when calling the PutEventSelectors operation: The operation requested is not supported in the region.

The error is a bit confusing, as eu-west-1 should support this? I'm a bit confused at how to set this up correctly - or why it's so hard to exclude CloudWatch events. The current setup does have a lot of lambdas in an intentional verbose state! I even think we thought the purpose of having CloudTrail was to log AWS user activity, so that we can track if one of our engineers tinkers with something unintentionally so that we can tack back faults - it wasn't really intended to log our lambda activity.
Any ideas on how to help appreciated.. If it's not possible, I would also would love to know as to why not (if you know!)

The eventSource is not supported with the Management Events, and when you don't specify any eventCategory in your command, CloudTrail assumes Management Events by default. when something wrong is written within the aws cloud-trail command, sometime you get weird errors.
AWS designed CloudTrail for comprehensive auditing, ensuring critical management actions are not accidentally excluded. Since Lambda’s interaction with CloudWatch is service-to-service, these are still considered “write” events and logged as part of management activity. so AWS cloudtrail tracks all the API calls within the AWS account, it doesn't matter wether a service has done it, or an IAM user.
You can restrict the logging to just the Write management events, this can significantly reduce the volume of logged interactions.
aws cloudtrail put-event-selectors --trail-name test-trail --region eu-west-1 --event-selectors '[
  {
    "ReadWriteType": "WriteOnly",
    "IncludeManagementEvents": true
  }
]'

or
aws cloudtrail put-event-selectors --trail-name test-trail --region eu-west-1 --advanced-event-selectors '[{
  "Name": "Write Management Events",
  "FieldSelectors": [
    {"Field": "eventCategory", "Equals": ["Management"]},
    {"Field": "readOnly", "Equals": ["false"]}
  ]
}]'

Management Events log high-level control-plane API actions that manage AWS resources. These events include:

Creating, modifying, or deleting AWS resources (e.g., creating an S3 bucket, starting an EC2 instance, deploying a Lambda function).

Service configuration changes (e.g., updating an IAM policy, changing a security group rule).


so normally you will get rid of the non needed cloudwatch logs.

So I have it logging Write events only, and event category as Management; the problem is that it still captures the CreateLogStream event which I would like to exclude, as that is quite literally responsible for 90% of the logs / costs. I can't seem to exclude this eventName while the management event is enabled. Like you have suggested, in my second query I have specified an eventCategory as Data (so that it does not assume management), but still get the error when calling the PutEventSelectors operation: The operation requested is not supported in the region. (eu-west-1).
